# matlab random number generation in parfor loop

Tags: matlab, random, parallel-processing, parfor

I want to generate same normal random numbers for loop and parfor loop. Following MATLAB documentation I tried three different method:

**Method 1: Using rng(seed, 'twister')**

```
N = 1;

for ind = 1:10
    rng(ind, 'twister')
    samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

plot(samps); hold on

parfor ind = 1:10
    rng(ind, 'twister')
    samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

scatter(1:length(samps), samps)
legend({'using for loop', 'using parfor loop'})
```

[image: By using rng twister method]

**Method 2: Using RandStream Method**

```
N = 1;
 
sc = parallel.pool.Constant(RandStream('Threefry'));
for ind = 1:10
    stream = sc.Value;
    stream.Substream = ind;
    samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

plot(samps); hold on

sc = parallel.pool.Constant(RandStream('Threefry'));
parfor ind = 1:10
       stream = sc.Value;
       stream.Substream = ind;
       samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

scatter(1:length(samps), samps)
legend({'using for loop', 'using parfor loop'})
```

[image: Using Threefry stream-substream method]

**Method 3: Using another RandStream method**

```
N = 1;
 
stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a');
for ind = 1:10
    stream.Substream = ind;
    samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

plot(samps); hold on

stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a');
parfor ind = 1:10
       set(stream,'Substream',ind);
       samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
end

scatter(1:length(samps), samps)
legend({'using for loop', 'using parfor loop'})
```

[image: Another randStream method]

My question is why the last two methods are not working. If I understood MATLAB documentation correctly, they should have worked. Also, is there anything wrong with using `rng(seed, 'twister')` method with different seeds to produce statistically independent samples?

**Edit:**
Here is the [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/repeat-random-numbers-in-parfor-loops.html) to the MATLAB documentation that I used.

Comment: What do you mean they are not working?? You showed us the plots they made so obviously they are working

Comment: 'By working' I mean for and parfor loops should be providing the same results for al three methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cris points out, `normrnd` uses the current global stream. Here's how to make your 3rd case match between client and workers - you need to set the global stream explicitly. (Note that I'm reverting the global stream immediately after using it too).

```
N = 1;

stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a');
for ind = 1:10
    stream.Substream = ind;
    prev = RandStream.setGlobalStream(stream);
    samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
    RandStream.setGlobalStream(prev);
end

stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a');
parfor ind = 1:10
    set(stream,'Substream',ind);
    prev = RandStream.setGlobalStream(stream);
    pf_samps(ind) = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
    RandStream.setGlobalStream(prev);
end
```

With this code, `samps` and `pf_samps` are identical.

Also, you should not use "twister" in parallel, since the random samples you obtain by setting the seed in this way will not have as good qualities as if you use a "parallel" generator like mrg32k3a. (I'm no expert, but my understanding is that the twister "seed" values are not able to select statistically-independent sequences of samples in the way that streams/substreams can)

In recent versions of MATLAB, faster generators that support multiple streams are available. See the doc https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-controlling-a-random-number-stream.html#brvku_2 . Philox and Threefry in particular are good parallel generators.

Comment: Thanks Edric. I have two more questions. 
(1) Changing the global stream is actually working. However, I do not understand the need for reverting back to global stream. In fact, I am getting the same results in case of for and parfor without `RandStream.setGlobalStream(prev)`.

(2) Yes, twister algorithm seemed to be giving statistically dependent simulations. But it gives the same results in case of for and parfor loops. So if it is okay to use it in for loop, why is it not okay to use it in parfor loop?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta What Edric said is that you don’t get good random numbers with the twist generator seeded in the way you do. It is bad practice no matter what type of loop it is. The other generators produce better randomness when “split off” into substreams.

Comment: @Cris I get it now.

Comment: I revert the global random stream just to be tidy really.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring that your concern is that the pseudorandomly generated numbers for your `for` and `parfor` loops did not match. This is however expected behavior. You used a MRG32K3A pseudorandom algorithm, which "does not make a guarantee that a fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to mrg32k3a.RandomState methods using the same parameters will always produce the same results." [Source.](https://bashtage.github.io/ng-numpy-randomstate/doc/mrg32k3a.html)

So it appears that everything is working correctly.

Comment: It is highly likely that I did not understand it correctly. But should not the code `set(stream,'Substream',ind);` inside parfor loop be giving the reproducible results.

Comment: The quoted text applies to the `randomstate` package in _Python_, and might not necessarily apply to the `RandStream` method in MATLAB in conjunction with `parfor`.

Comment: I see. I read from MATLAB documentation that it also applies to MATLAB parfor. again, it is likely that I am reading something incorrectly. But I have not been able to figure it out. I have provided the link to the documentation in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `normrnd(0,1,N,1)`, you are not using `stream` to generate a random number, but rather the default RNG. Instead, use `randn(stream,N,1)`, see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html).

As far as I can tell, `normrnd` and other generators from the Statistics and a Machine Learning toolbox always use the default RNG, and cannot use a custom `RandStream` object.